# MERGE the Creation of Nodes from Two geohash Columns in CSV

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I am planning to create a geohash Graph with neo4j.

my CSV contains ,for each row, two informations for geohash one for **pickup** and another for **dropoff** as follow :
[image: Pre-processed data]

What I want is:

- the node that have the same geohash as another one shouldn't be recreated (so multiple edges are allowed).
- one node could be a pickup and a dropoff in the same time

I tried to use `MERGE` but works by columns:

```
load csv from "file:///green_data.csv" as line
merge(pick:pickup{geohash:line[20]})merge (drop:dropoff{geohash: line[22]})merge(pick)-[:trip]->(drop)
```

[image: merge]

as you can see , the same geohash `dr5rkky` node is being created twice one for pickups and another for dropoffs

how to avoid that ?

Comment: Your labels are different so it will create two node, if label is not important use one equal label for pickup and dropoff

Comment: thanks @Saeed that Solve the problem if i use the same label as you suggested ,however the label is important to identify which node is pickup and which is a drop-off

Comment: also if i want to add the timehash as property to the node. so is there a way to make neo4j identify nodes by the geohash property only ???

Comment: You can add node with one label. and add pickup and drop-off as property to your node

Comment: @Saeed i tried your suggestion that dosen't work two different nodes are created.

Comment: load csv from "file:///green_data.csv" as line
merge(pick:pickup{geohash:line[20],nature:"pickup"})merge (drop:pickup{geohash: line[22],nature:"dropoff"})merge(pick)-[:trip]->(drop)

Comment: First set CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:pickup) ASSERT n.geohash IS UNIQUE, second add your nature property in on create and on match

Comment: could you put that in an answer please it is not clear for me cause i m beginner with cypher

Comment: is answer work fine?

Comment: yes thank you so much, but if you can explain more why that works on create and on match unlike  setting it directly  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
load csv from "file:///green_data.csv" as line MERGE(p:HashNode {geohash: line[20]}) ON CREATE set p.pickup=True ON MATCH set p.pickup=True MERGE(d:HashNode {geohash: line[22]}) ON CREATE set d.dropoff=True ON MATCH set d.dropoff=True MERGE (p)-[:trip]->(d)
```

Base on [neo4j docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/):

> MERGE either matches existing nodes and binds them, or it creates new data and binds that. It’s like a combination of MATCH and CREATE that additionally allows you to specify what happens if the data was matched or created.
>   The last part of MERGE is the ON CREATE and ON MATCH. These allow a query to express additional changes to the properties of a node or relationship, depending on if the element was MATCH -ed in the database or if it was CREATE -ed.

Comment: Hi @Saeed i want to do the same thing ith [CAPS](https://github.com/opencypher/cypher-for-apache-spark) do you know how ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about CAPS